# Flutter | How to authenticate registered users with http.post()

Tags: flutter, api, http

so I'm trying to authenticate registered users using `http.post()` using https://reqres.in/ API.

this is the method I'm using

```
register(BuildContext context) {
    http
        .post(Uri.parse('http://reqres.in/api/register'), body: _user)
        .then((value) {
      
      var valJson = json.decode(value.body);
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
          .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("$valJson")));
      if (valJson['error'] != null) {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            SnackBar(content: Text("ERROR: ${valJson['error']}")));
      } else {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            const SnackBar(content: Text("Registered successfully")));
      }
    });
  }
```

the error in this line: `var valJson = json.decode(value.body);` it shows that the body is empty! according to reqres.in this information should return no error

```
{
    "email": "eve.holt@reqres.in",
    "password": "pistol"
}
```

and in my case, it should show `Snackbar` with a success message, but it the `Snackbar` is not showing up at all!

I'm using this method inside a `Form()` widget

```
Map<String, String> _user = {};
...
return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          TextFormField(
            validator: (value) {
              _user['email'] = value.trim();
            },
          ),
          TextFormField(
            validator: (value) {
              _user['password'] = value.trim();
            },
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
                _user['email'] = nameValue;
                _user['password'] = passValue;
                register(context);            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

please help, thank you

Comment: Try to decode value first:  var valJson = json.decode(value); then get the body from valJson.body

Comment: @RidhaRezzag it showed this error `The argument type 'Response' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'` then used `toString()` on value, but `valJson` turned out to be `dynamic` and `.body` can only be accessed if it is `Response`